# I am confused about customizing ROMs

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to upgrade my Tivax MiTraveler tablet to run the latest version of Android. Unfortunately, the updater claims there are no updates available. Looking at this log file I obtained from backing up the device, it appears to be a generic hardware configuration:

```
ro.build.version.sdk=17
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=4.2.2
ro.build.user=inet_wupangpang
ro.build.host=supperFAE
ro.product.model=97D16W
ro.product.brand=softwinners
ro.product.name=wing_ibt
ro.product.device=wing-ibt
ro.product.board=wing
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=AWT
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
ro.board.platform=exDroid
ro.build.product=wing-ibt
ro.build.description=wing_ibt-eng 4.2.2 JDQ39 20130620 test-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=softwinners/wing_ibt/wing-ibt:4.2.2/JDQ39/20130620:eng/test-keys
ro.build.characteristics=tablet
ro.com.android.dateformat=MM-dd-yyyy
ro.build.display.id=A20_K9701_K9701L3B_1305282.20130620
persist.sys.timezone=Asia/Shanghai
ro.inet.LauncherTransparent=false
ro.product.firmware=1.3_20130614
net.bt.name=Android
net.change=net.bt.name
```

This appears to be a plain vanilla build configuration, but I am confused about how to go about updating the system. I couldn't find a specific firmware for my device, but I found several devices that use the exact same hardware and firmware.  Unfortunately, none of them support a higher version of Android.

I noticed the firmware has two layers: linux and Android.  The Android layer runs on top of Linux and appears to be a set of Java applications. Is it possible to replace just the Android components and reflash firmware?  If it Android uses a JVM, it should work, No? If it is compiled Java, it should work provided you use the same Allwinners target, No?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! May I suggest you start with reading our [updating tag-wiki](/tags/updates/info), and follow up some of its links? That would give you some background. Also helpful in your context: our [rom tag-wiki](/tags/rom/info).

Comment: Build.prop is not "a configuration to generate a build from" - in fact it's like the reverse, i.e. "a property list of a generated build". Building ROMs is so much more than you might think.

Comment: @AndyYan   I am not assuming anything about its complexity, which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: It's a bit more than just replacing the Android parts, You'd need kernel updates most of the time.

Comment: Cool.  I will attempt a build.  Allwinners has an open source project for various UNIX flavors. There are a few drivers that are proprietary, but with luck they may be unnecessary or might be binary compatible. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

this log from the system process is the properties of your device and you can change the version in the file build.prop in the /system directory loop the pics :[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]